# Is there a standard way of Identifying 'Domain not Owned' sites when using http/https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect

I am using a node webshot library to take a image of an web site say at http://x.y.z.com/blah . If the website exists I get a nice image. If the website does not exist I may or may not get an error. If I get an error case I can use a default image. However, I am finding out that some domains are being redirected to the infamous Domain selling sites or a "search for" Domain site. For example, http://notawebsite.com.org is redirected to http://www.com.org/?notfound=notawebsite.com.org. I have also checked dns to see if I can invalidate the site ahead of time but it resolves fine ( to the www.com.org address ). So is there anything I can do to determine if a url site is redirected to one of theses Domain search/selling sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard way of Identifying 'Domain not Owned' sites when using http/https?

No, not really.  In the example you cite, the server for `http://notawebsite.com.org` returns a 301 redirect.  It seems to me that you just decide that if you're getting a redirect to a different domain (and not just a redirect to a different page on the same domain and not just a redirect from http to https on the same domain), then the URL you were attempting to access is apparently not active on its own.

There is no standard way to know whether the site you are redirect to is just a domain seller vs. an actual active domain.  You could manually investigate a bunch of sites you get redirects on and teach your code how to identify some common domain sellers doing this, but that would be a somewhat unending task that probably need regular human intervention to tell the difference between a real site and a domain selling site.  You could, in the end, built up a blacklist of domain seller's domains and refuse to catalog any URL that redirects to any domain on your blacklist.  But, it would probably take some manual intervention to build and maintain the blacklist.

You also have no way of knowing for sure that all URLs on a given domain where you're getting a redirect do a similar redirect, but you can certainly say that the URL you tried to get the snapshot from is not directly active on its own.  If the user goes to that domain in their browser, they won't see any content for that domain in their browser because the redirect will change the URL.

> So is there anything I can do to determine if a url site is redirected to one of theses Domain search/selling sites?

Build your own blacklist of reseller domains that show up in redirects like this.  Then whenever you attempt to request a page URL for purposes of grabbing a webshot and you get a 3xx status code back from the request, you check the redirect domain to see if it is on your blacklist.

Comment: Thanks, you at least confirmed what I was thinking.

Comment: @Cjolly - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.